# Running docker with java permission issue

Tags: java, docker

I want to create a docker with java and test it, however I get an error

This is the docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim

…



COPY  Simple.java /project/


WORKDIR /project

CMD ["java" ,”--version”]
```

I try to run the file `Simple.java`

```
class Simple{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

when I run the following command:

`docker run mydocker  javac Simple.java`

I get the error:

```
Simple.java:1: error: error while writing Simple: Simple.class (Permission denied)
class Simple{
^
1 error
```

How could I test a simple java program and see that it works?

Comment: in your Simple.java change class name to `public class Simple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding the command(CMD) in dockerfile when you run

```
docker run mydocker  javac Simple.java
```

Here what [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) says:

> This command is optional because the person who created the IMAGE may have already provided a default COMMAND using the Dockerfile CMD instruction. As the operator (the person running a container from the image), you can override that CMD instruction just by specifying a new COMMAND

I changed your Dockerfile a bit, here:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim

COPY  Simple.java /project/

WORKDIR /project

RUN ["javac" ,"Simple.java"]
CMD ["java" ,"Simple"]
```

Now you should be able to run

```
docker run mydocker
```

Output;

```
➜ DockerTest docker run mydocker
Hello Java
```